# Debugging Pulumi "ResourceNotReady: exceeded wait attempts"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, pulumi

I am trying to deploy a fargate service on AWS ECS with Pulumi as IaC.

Everything works as expected when deploying my Fargate service with:

```
deploymentController: {
    type: "ECS"
},
```

But changing it to:

```
deploymentController: {
    type: "CODE_DEPLOY"
},
```

Ends with error message: "ResourceNotReady: exceeded wait attempts"

Is there any way to debug this that would help me to find out what resource Pulumi is waiting for?

Is there some hidden dependencies for Blue/Green deployment on ECS that is not obvious when deploying with Pulumi?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: I switched to aws cdk instead. But I suspect that it has to do with dependencies not being met. I did not find any good solution to the problem though.

Comment: what exactly fdid you do differently with cdk?

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying to an ECS Cluster living within a different stack than your Fargate service stack?
If so then that's the reason behin the timeout error. Cause the stack isn't able to ping the service and make sure it's steady ready, since it's in a different stack.